Good reading source for conditional DID
What book/article would you recommend for some practical aspects of conditional diff-in-diff?

Could, perhaps be a little more specific? First of all, there's a lot of literature on DD. Secondly, people usually "misuse" the DD-concept also to include other research designs with multiple treatment groups with differences in the timing of treatment. Thirdly, it is very unclear what is meant by "practical" aspects. ... anyway here is a nice review article: https://bcallaway11.github.io/files/Callaway-Chapter-2022/main.pdf and good introduction is perhaps chapter 9 of scott cunninghams book: https://mixtape.scunning.com/09-difference_in_differences
